# launch process in background and modify it from bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm creating a bash script that will run a process in the background, which creates a socket file. The socket file then needs to be `chmod`'d. The problem I'm having is that the socket file isn't being created before trying to `chmod` the file.

Example source:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# first create folder that will hold socket file
mkdir /tmp/myproc
# now run process in background that generates the socket file
node ../main.js &
# finally chmod the thing
chmod /tmp/myproc/*.sock
```

How do I delay the execution of the `chmod` until after the socket file has been created?

Comment: Just an idea, don't know if it is valid: can't you signal from main.js when the socket is been created and, on the other hand, wait in your script until you receive that signal?

Comment: May be a possibility, but I'm not sure how that would be structured in bash.

Comment: Did you try using an *inotify* based [tool](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/#wiki-info) to keep a tab on when the file is created?

Comment: Never heard of inotify. I'll look that up and report back.

Comment: If the socket needs to be `chmod`'d, why doesn't `main.js` do it? Conversely, would it be better to create the socket prior to running `main.js'`? (Assuming `main.js` is under your control).

Comment: creating the socket before running `main.js` won't work because the script will just overwrite it. I did think about implementing the `chmod` in the app, but since this is just for a very specific dev instance thought there might be a quick fix in bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test to see if the file exists before proceeding:

```
while [[ ! -e filename ]]
do
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: What if I want to check for a specific number of files matching a pattern? (e.g. continue only when there are 5 files matching `mysock[0-9].sock`)

Comment: @TrevNorris: Use an array with a glob and check the count of array elements: `shopt -s nullglob; while a=(mysock{0..9}.sock); ((${#a[@]} < 5)); do sleep 1; done`

Comment: mostly worked. had to change `(mysock{0..9}.sock)` to `(/tmp/myproc/mysock*.sock)`. but that's a pretty sick trick to show the count of the array elements.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I know to do this is to busywait for the file to appear. Conveniently, `ls` returns non-zero when the file it is asked to list doesn't exist; so just loop on `ls` until it returns 0, and when it does you know you have at least one `*.sock` file to chmod.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Waiting for socket to open.."
( while [ ! $(ls /tmp/myproc/*.sock) ]; do
  echo -n "."
  sleep 2
done ) 2> /dev/null
echo ". Found"
```

If this is something you need to do more than once wrap it in a function, but otherwise as is should do what you need.

EDIT:

As pointed out in the comments, using ls like this is inferior to -e in the test, so the rewritten script below is to be preferred. (I have also corrected the shell invocation, as -n is not supported on all platforms in sh emulation mode.)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Waiting for socket to open.."
while [ ! -e /tmp/myproc/*.sock ]; do
  echo -n "."
  sleep 2
done
echo ". Found"
```

Comment: No, loop on `[[ -e filename ]]`. `ls` is not necessary and not intended for this purpose. You haven't redirected the error messages that it will output - instead you throw away all potential errors in a useless subshell (use curly brackets for that purpose if you must). It's not necessary to use the square brackets and command substitution since `if` can test the return value if a command (which is what it does with `[` which is a command) including negating it with `!`.

Comment: Especially since you say you're going to test the return value when what you're really doing when using the square brackets and command substitution is testing the text output by `ls`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson You are correct, I was careless. I have edited to include your suggested improvement. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you set your [umask](http://ss64.com/bash/umask.html) (try `umask 0`) you may not have to chmod at all. If you still don't get the right permissions check if node has options to change that.